# Htaccess with PHP array/MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Currently am having my own CDN like server, where i can host my common files to serve in all my domains & also with limited users [i mean my clients] can access the common files. adding RewriteCond `%{HTTP_REFERER}` all times by editing `.htacess` manually. But, i need to manage it dynamically as `PHP` array or `MySql` table, where i can manage all domain names in my control panel.

Any ideas or suggestions?

TIA.

Comment: You know that HTTP_REFERER is not a 'safe' value since it can get manipulated easily. So access is not really limited to your clients. But to your question: Why not simply write a (php-)application that modifies your .htaccess dynamically?

Comment: Any replacement instead of  HTTP_REFERER? By the way, Writing PHP application to edit entire htacess file is also a great idea. :)

Comment: If you want to restrict access and manage it in a robust way, probably some sort of real authentication stored with cookies is the way to go. I'd be careful modifying the htaccess, too as an error can make the whole directory serve a 500.

Comment: Thanks for the info JAL & Michael Helwig